# iPad simulator broken

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

iPad simulator won't run my app! It loads and animates in and then crashes halfway through the loading animation.

Xcode reports: Debugging Terminated. Why?

I just had this on my iPod touch (8GB) and I rebooted them both.

EDIT:

This code in the delegate seems to be causing an issue:

`NSLog(@"Device: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]);`

Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: Is your target ver. 3.2 or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]` does not return an object, which is required by `%@` format specifier.

Try `NSLog(@"Device: %d", [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]);`

Comment: And make sure you check you're not on 3.1.3 or earlier before you call that, by wrapping in an respondsToSelector...

Comment: Tom really should get the credit for this.  As he is right.  This would crash if you are earlier than 3.2

Comment: Moshe confirmed 3.2 or later as a target.